# Java Card: Data encryption/decryption with RSA

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, card

I want to create an Applet using the Java Card technology for encrypting and decrypting strings with RSA. Currently, I'm trying to do it within the Oracle IDE using its CREF simulator (having Java Card v3.1.0), but afterwards I'd like to try it on my smart card NXP J3H145 which has the Java Card v3.0.4 on it. In the constructor, I've set the stage like this:

```
short KeySize=(short)64;
RSA_PRIV_KEY_EXP=JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((byte) KeySize, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
RSA_PUB_KEY_EXP=JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((byte) KeySize, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
RSA_PUB_PRIV_KEY_MOD=JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((byte) KeySize, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_RESET);
for (short i=0;i<KeySize;i++) {
  RSA_PRIV_KEY_EXP[i]=1;
  RSA_PUB_KEY_EXP[i]=1;
  RSA_PUB_PRIV_KEY_MOD[i]=1;
}
pair=new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA,KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);
RSAPublicKey pubKey=(RSAPublicKey)pair.getPublic();
RSAPrivateKey privKey=(RSAPrivateKey)pair.getPrivate();
pubKey.setExponent(RSA_PUB_KEY_EXP, (short) 0, (short) RSA_PUB_KEY_EXP.length);
pubKey.setModulus(RSA_PUB_PRIV_KEY_MOD, (short) 0, (short) RSA_PUB_PRIV_KEY_MOD.length);
privKey.setExponent(RSA_PRIV_KEY_EXP, (short) 0, (short) RSA_PRIV_KEY_EXP.length);
privKey.setModulus(RSA_PUB_PRIV_KEY_MOD, (short) 0, (short) RSA_PUB_PRIV_KEY_MOD.length);
pair.genKeyPair();
Cipher cip=Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1_OAEP, false);
```

Then, my encryption method looks like this and works fine:

```
private void encrypt(APDU apdu) {
  byte[] buffer=apdu.getBuffer();
  short lc=buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
  RSAPublicKey pub=(RSAPublicKey) pair.getPublic();
  cip.init(pub, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
  byte[] temp=new byte[2048];
  short cipLen = cip.doFinal(buffer, (short)ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, lc, temp, (short) 0);
  apdu.setOutgoing();
  apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)cipLen);
  apdu.sendBytesLong(temp, (short) 0, (short)cipLen);
}
```

For example, if I try to send three bytes "1 2 3" to the encryption method, it encrypts them and returns an array of 63 bytes. Now, I would like to pass that array to my decryption method and to receive my original string back. My decryption method looks like this:

```
private void decrypt(APDU apdu) {
  try {
    byte[] buffer=apdu.getBuffer();
    short lc=buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
    RSAPrivateKey priv=(RSAPrivateKey)pair.getPrivate();
    cip.init(priv, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
    byte[] temp=new byte[2048];
    short cipLen = cip.doFinal(buffer, (short)ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, lc, temp, (short) 0);
    apdu.setOutgoing();
    apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)cipLen);
    apdu.sendBytesLong(temp, (short) 0, (short)cipLen);
  }
  catch (CryptoException e) {
    short a=e.getReason();
  }
}
```

Here, the "doFinal" method call throws a CryptoException with the reason code 5. I have found that the reason code 5 means there is some kind of problem with the padding algorithm or the padding of input data or smth like this. I suspect that perhaps I've written something wrong in the constructor, in the final line where I call the "getInstance" method of my Cipher. However, I've tried using various kinds of parameters for this method instead of ALG_RSA_PKCS1_OAEP (I've also tried to pass two parameters - one for the cipher algorithm and one for the padding algorithm -, but nothing has worked so far.

It seems like a simple problem - just to encrypt and decrypt data and to receive the original input -, but I have not managed to even find any examples of how it could be done and I've spent so much time on this error... Can anyone point me to the problem with the exception and to how to get rid of it? I don't even care about the particular length of the keys or of the encrypted string, I just want one solution that works.

Comment: So, my question is still open... Anybody? I guess I have some fundamental misunderstanding with that padding of input data or smth. I tried implementing the AES algorithm meanwhile - everything works correctly only when I provide input data of the length of exactly 16 bytes (my data get encrypted and decrypted flawlessly). If I try 15 bytes, I get the same CryptoException with the reason code 5 (in this case, I initialize the Cipher instance like this: ```Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_AES_BLOCK_128_CBC_NOPAD, false);```).

Comment: I forgot to mention in my previous comment that I get that exception also using other Cipher algorithms besides the ..._NOPAD. I tried out all of them, I think, with no luck.